# predictions on level data ( with group models)

Tags: r

I am in desperate need of help: So I am using dplyr to run regressions by group. I.e something like this:

```
regressions <- mtcars %>% group_by(cyl) %>%
do(fit = lm(wt ~ mpg + qsec + gear, .))
```

and I get models in a dataframe that looks like this:

```
  ##     cyl     fit
  ##   (dbl)   (chr)
  ## 1     4 <S3:lm>
  ## 2     6 <S3:lm>
  ## 3     8 <S3:lm>
```

Now I want to predict on new data that is shorter (i.e not the same dimention as my training data), and that have the same levels. I.e 4,6,8 for cyl. My question then is: How do I predict using the new/testdata such that each model refers to only their level in my test set.

```
 so model cyl 4 only uses data 4 cyl to predict 
model cyl 6 uses data 6 cyl to predict
model cyl 8 uses data 8 cyl to predict
and so on and so forth.enter code here
```

Please keep in mind the test data has all the levels/groups in it.

Is there an easier way to do this. I.e to make predictions by levels. currently I am trying to use augment in the broom package but it doesn't really work. what it does is: it runs each model through all my test data while disregarding the level.

Please help! I am doing this on a much larger scale and need something that is quick and efficient.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This might be a good job for **purrr** along with **dplyr** and **tidyr**.  The  **purrr** package is made to work with lists, and I believe will replace `do` in the long run.

For example, if you had a test dataset with the same variables in it, which I'm calling `mtcars_test`.

```
mtcars_test = mtcars
```

You can split this dataset into three pieces based on `cyl`.

```
test_split = split(mtcars_test, mtcars_test$cyl)
```

Then you can use `map2` to run through the three models along with the split test data to make the predictions.  Note this relies on the models and list of dataset to be in the same cylinder order, so be careful.

```
library(purrr)

map2(regressions$fit, test_split, predict)
```

The result is a list.  Make nicer looking output of the function to get the output into a data.frame with `map2_dfr()`.

```
map2_dfr(regressions$fit, test_split, 
     function(model, newdata) {
          newdata$pred = predict(model, newdata = newdata)
          newdata
     })

                     mpg cyl  disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb     pred
Datsun 710          22.8   4 108.0  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1 2.463345
Merc 240D           24.4   4 146.7  62 3.69 3.190 20.00  1  0    4    2 2.633560
Merc 230            22.8   4 140.8  95 3.92 3.150 22.90  1  0    4    2 3.392781
Fiat 128            32.4   4  78.7  66 4.08 2.200 19.47  1  1    4    1 1.864082
Honda Civic         30.4   4  75.7  52 4.93 1.615 18.52  1  1    4    2 1.821926
Toyota Corolla      33.9   4  71.1  65 4.22 1.835 19.90  1  1    4    1 1.834495
...
```

In your real case, you may want to end up with your results within the nested dataset.  I couldn't get things to work with `do()`, but this is possible in **dplyr 1.0.0** with `nest_by()` and list output.  The `unnest()` function is from **tidyr**.

```
library(tidyr)

regs2 = mtcars %>%
     nest_by(cyl) %>%
     mutate(fit = list(lm(wt ~ mpg + qsec + gear, data = data)))
```

To loop through the models and the new dataset list with `map2()` within `mutate()`, the dataset must be ungrouped.  I remove the other list columns in the output here before unnesting, but that isn't strictly necessary.

```
regs2 %>%
     ungroup() %>%
     mutate(test_pred = map2(fit, test_split, predict) ) %>%
     select(-data, -fit) %>%
     unnest(test_pred) 

# A tibble: 32 x 2
     cyl test_pred
   <dbl>     <dbl>
 1     4      2.46
 2     4      2.63
 3     4      3.39
 4     4      1.86
 5     4      1.82
 6     4      1.83
 7     4      2.61
 8     4      2.16
 9     4      2.06
10     4      1.74
# ... with 22 more rows
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the response. Is there a way to use the same logic to run, say an ARIMA model with auto.arima function or a holtwinters using the same logic? i.e splitting the dataset as above, running a holtwinters,  then returning a forecast for say x number of periods for each.

Answer (score 0):

I had some problem getting to the `lm`objects within the data.frame so the first loop is not pretty:

```
A <- list()
for (i in unique(mtcars$cyl)) {
  A[[as.character(i)]] <- predict(as.list(regressions[regressions$cyl == i, ])$fit[[1]],
                    newdata = mtcars[mtcars$cyl == i, ])
}
```

A simpler solution would be to do both steps (regression then predicting) inside the same loop.

```
reg <- list()
pred <- list()
for (cyl in unique(mtcars$cyl)) {
  reg[[as.character(cyl)]] <- lm(wt ~ mpg + qsec + gear, filter(mtcars, cyl == cyl))
  pred[[as.character(cyl)]] <- predict(reg[[as.character(cyl)]],
                                       newdata = filter(mtcars, cyl == cyl))
}
```

Obviously, you can use `lapply` for either of those two methods on `unqieu(mtcars$cyl)` directly. In both cases I used `as.character` on the loop iterator to ensure that your results' list does not increment up to six cylinders leaving five empty spots.

Finally, you could use the `*` element to cross all your variables with the `cyl` variable so that you are de facto creating as many models as groups. You can then simply use predict directly without having to subset. Note that I switched the `cyl` variable to `factor` class in order to ensure I would have one slope by group. I also specified the intercept explicitly inside the formula parenthesis to ensure a different intercept by group.

```
mtcars$cyl <- factor(mtcars$cyl)
reg <- lm(wt ~ (1 + mpg + qsec + gear)*cyl, mtcars)
predict(reg, mtcars)
```

The only problem with this approach is that coefficients are more difficult to interpret, (ie: the coefficient for `mpg` for group `cyl = 6` is the coefficient for `mpg` plus the coefficient for `mpg:cyl6`)

Answer (score 0):

This is extremely compactly and easily achieved using `broom::augment`.

You fit the regressions and score:

```
library(broom)
library(dplyr)

# fit the set of regressions by cyl
regressions = mtcars %>% group_by(cyl) %>%
  do(fit = lm(wt ~ mpg + qsec + gear, .))

# score the regressions by cyl
scores = regressions %>% 
  augment(fit)
```

You can check that the results of this are the same as the results of individual regression fits and scoring for groups defined by values of `cyl`.

```
# check that regression with cyl == 4 and predictions gives the same result
lm_4 = lm(wt ~ mpg + qsec + gear, data = subset(mtcars, cyl == 4))
predict(lm_4, newdata = subset(mtcars, cyl == 4))
scores %>% 
  filter(cyl == 4)

# check that regression with cyl == 8 and predictions gives the same result
lm_8 = lm(wt ~ mpg + qsec + gear, data = subset(mtcars, cyl == 8))
predict(lm_8, newdata = subset(mtcars, cyl == 8))
scores %>% 
  filter(cyl == 8)
```

Comment: `augment` is great for predictions on the training set, but I didn't see how to use it for make predictions with a new test set.

Comment: @aosmith Thanks for your comment. `augment` supports a `newdata` argument. Please see the documentation for `augment.lm`.

Comment: Does the new data have to be split by the factor before using it or can you define the correct subset to use for predictions for each group within `augment` somehow?

Comment: @aosmith It works the exact way that it would work on the original data (which I have demonstrated). Indeed, a moment's thought should convince you that the behavior cannot be different.

Comment: Thank you to all who responded, I truly appreciate it!

Comment: @tcharkravarty: while augment works on a new data set, It does not predict using only level specific data: For instance, it uses lm_4 to predict all the  levels in the newdata, lm_8 to predict all the levels and so on and so forth. It doesn't know to predict just on the data referring to a specific model, if that makes sense. Is there a way to specify such that each model created is used to predict on the newdata that is associated with that model? so lm_4 predicts using only the data of cyl=4. Keep in mind that the new dataset have all the original levels put together.

Comment: @AliceWork Please ask a new question and try to be more detailed about what you mean. I am not sure I understand your requirement.